# Meteor External API Call Problems

Tags: javascript, rest, meteor

I'm learning Meteor and am trying to make a very basic app that returns data from an external API. I'll increase the complexity as I go, but right now I'd just like to get the API call to work properly.

Here are the basics of what I have so far:

On the server -

```
var url = "http://example.com";
var username = "user";
var apiKey = "key";

Meteor.methods({
    callFltAware: function() {
        this.unblock();
        return HTTP.get(url, {
        auth: "user:key",
    query: {"origin": "x", "destination": "x"} 
        });
    }
});
```

On the client -

```
Template.airportForm.events({
    "click input": function() {
    callFltAware();
    }
})

Meteor.call("callFltAware", function(e,r) {
    if (!e && r) {
        console.log(r.statusCode, r.data);
    }
})
```

I get a 200 status code, but the data returned is empty. Does this mean it's an API problem?

I'm pretty new to web development, so it could be a very simple mistake I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

the `.data` would contain JSON parsed data. Have a look at `.content` instead.

Only if the content can be parsed as JSON then you would have something in `.data`, otherwise it would be `null`.

Comment: Still empty. Sent a question to the service provider to see if I'm sending the query incorrectly.